# Why is my firestore query not working for a specific collection?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get a specific document from a firestore collection and get its ID.

Everything else works except the part where the fetching part (the query, I suppose).

If I change the collection to query, everything works perfectly.

My code

```
val country = binding.autoCompleteTv.text.toString().trim()
Log.d(BusinessDetailsFragment.TAG, country)
    firebaseFirestore.collection("Countries")
        .whereEqualTo("countryName", country)
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
            for (document in documents) {
                Log.d(BusinessDetailsFragment.TAG, "${document.id} => ${document.data}")
                countryID = document.id
                Toast.makeText(this, countryID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.w(BusinessDetailsFragment.TAG, "Error getting documents: ", exception)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Firestore Collection]

For some reason, this is not working. My logcat sometimes says tells me that my device internet might be weak but I don't think that is the problem.

[image: Logcat]

As you can see, the auto-complete textview's value is being fetched successfully.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: "this is not working" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors?

Comment: Just warnings. No errors at all. The objective of that piece of code is to search for a document that contains a certain "countryName" and fetch its ID. That's what is not working but only for the "Countries" collection. If I put any other collection with its relevant field, the code works. Let me try to attach the logcat on the question too.

Comment: Does any of the log statements print something? What is the value of `country` inside your query?

Comment: Turns out the log statements after the for loop aren't printing anything. I inserted another one right before the for loop... it's printing the correct value of the country as per the auto-complete textview.

Comment: What is the value of country inside your query?

Comment: It changes every time depending on what I have selected on the auto complete textview. The value being passed inside the query is the correct one every time. No issues there.

Comment: Have you tried to use a hard-coded value? Does it work that way?